# How to position taxonomy meta box on page

Tags: taxonomy, taxonomy-meta

I have successfully added a meta box to my custom taxonomy "attributes" using the following code:

```
add_action( 'attribute_add_form_fields','add_icon_group_field', 10, 2 );

function add_icon_group_field($taxonomy) {
    ?><div class="form-field term-group">
        <label for="icon"><?php _e('Icon', 'blueleaf'); ?></label>
        <input class="icon-picker-input" name="icon" id="icon" type="text" value="" size="40">
    </div><?php
}
```

which works perfectly.  However, I'd like the meta box to appear above the "slug" box in the wordpress's admin, or at the very least above the description box - not at the bottom of the page.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, i.e. there isn't a hook that will allow you to do this. However, you could move them around after the fact with javascript, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I was hoping for a server-side solution.  I'm not sure it's worth doing it with javascript - it's not important enough to enqueue a file for!

Comment: Yeah unfortunately, as of 4.8.1 there isn't a hook to add your fields any sooner. I doubt they'll add it in the future but you're more than welcome to check out [WP Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/) and bring up your issue there.